# Some basic questions about Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, cdn

I know this isn't a direct technical problem but this seems like an ideal place to ask since I know other developers have experience using this service. I was about to ask this on the Amazon AWS forums but realized you need to be a AWS account holder to do that. I don't want to signup with them before getting the following answered:

1. Is Amazon S3 a CDN? or is it just an online storage service meant for personal use? Even if it isn't a CDN are you at least allowed to serve website assets from it to a high traffic site?
2. I have an adult dating site I would like to store assets for in S3? Is this type of site allowed under their tos? What they had to say on the matter in their tos was way too broad. Basically this site has nude images of members but they are all of age and uploaded by the users themselves. The site is targeted only to U.S. users and is legal under U.S. laws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazons S3 service can be used as a CDN if you want depending on the size of your site your might want to look at cloudfront which will allow you to have your content shared across multiple zones, for what your describing s3 will be fine for your needs but as for amazons rules with content im not to sure.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon stands for storage services.
You can use S3 to store files for private or public use.
If you want to use CDN services, you have to use Cloud Front.
Cloud front accepts S3 as input data to spread it to CDN servers.

About the policies, Im uncertain, but you can use it for store any type of data as long you have its rights.

Comment: You don't *have* to use CloudFront. Amazon S3 is fine for CDN as well, and they have a guide telling in which cases it is cheaper to use S3 and in which cases it is cheaper to use CloudFront.